# Spark Hive table join strategy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Hive table of 14 billion records (around 1TB of size) and another Hive table of 800 million records (2GB big). I want to join them, what should be my strategy?
I have a 36 node cluster. I am using 50 executors, 30 GB to each executor.

From what I see, my options are:

1. Broadcasting the 2 GB table
2. Just joining 2 tables blindly (I have done this, it's taking almost 4 hrs to complete)

If I repartition both the tables and join them, will it increase the performance?
I observed that in the 2nd approach the last 20 tasks are extremely slow, I am hoping they are processing partitions having more data (skewed data).

Comment: Did you take a look at the provided answer?

Answer (score 2):

The smaller table can fit into memory if you give each worker enough RAM. In that case a map side join / side data approach may well be useful.

Take a look at using the `MapJoin` hint:

```
SELECT /*+ MAPJOIN(b) */ a.key, a.value
FROM a JOIN b ON a.key = b.key
```

The essential point:

> If all but one of the tables being joined are small, the join can be
>   performed as a map only job.

More details on its usage may be seen here:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins#LanguageManualJoins-MapJoinRestrictions